# Error in JDBCTemplate Query in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate

i have used the following code(addAStudent and login methods )to perform Register and login operation for a simple Student Management System. I can able to execute the addAStudent method without any issues, but i am unable to execute the login method

```
@Override
    public void addAStudent(String firstName, String lastName, String middleName, String username, String password, String emailId)
    {
       JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate=new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
       jdbcTemplate.update("insert into Student(email_id,first_name,last_name,middle_name,password,username) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)",emailId,firstName,lastName,middleName,password,username);
    }
    @Override
    public void login(String username,String password)
    {
        
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate=new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate.query("select * from student_info where uname=? and password=?",username,password);
        
    }
```

please tell me, what is my mistake

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCiXV.png)

Comment: Any exceptoins? Does the `student_info` have `uname` and `password` columns?

Comment: It's hard to help you without 1) your spring config 2) error/exception logs.

Comment: The modified code is 
 JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate=new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate.query("select * from student where username=? and password=?",username,password);

Comment: give your stack trace && Student class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If yuo use java 8 then select like:

```
jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT s.username as c1, s.password as c2 from student s where s.username = ? and s.password = ?",
            new Object[]{username,password}),
            (rs ->{
                Student student = new Student();
                student.username = rs.getString("c1");
                student.passwrod = rs.getString("c2");
                return student;
            });
```

i think your table name `student`.

```
       jdbcTemplate.update("insert into student(email_id,first_name,last_name,middle_name,password,username) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)",emailId,firstName,lastName,middleName,password,username);
```